# FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I tried to make a new React app and i got this massage:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6C5A67A1F
 2: 00007FF6C59F6096
 3: 00007FF6C59F6F4D
 4: 00007FF6C632B2CE
 5: 00007FF6C63158AD
 6: 00007FF6C61B8C7C
 7: 00007FF6C6192B87
 8: 00007FF6C618FC18
 9: 00007FF6C61BFEE7
10: 00007FF6C61C2281
11: 00007FF6C61B5559
12: 00007FF6C61B3710
13: 00007FF6C61D8296
14: 00007FF6C5F0A61A
15: 00007FF6C63B8FC1
16: 000002249D95D370
```

Can somebody help me with that?
I'm using Windows.

Comment: Can you describe what you did to get the error? Also write down the nodejs version you are using

Comment: command: npx create-react-app reactlearning |
 node version: v16.15.0

Comment: [Cliffordwh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687382/10942809) works for me:
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=655300

Answer (score 1):

It's a OS related issue. In the virtual memory mapping of `linux` there is a maximum memory allocation, you can increase it with

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=655300
```

You should then be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

when there is a difference of node versions of the **downloaded** and Application configuration in **package.json** . We will face this error.

***Make Sure that both are same and Prefer having an LTS version for both Application and local downloaded one***